# WiX dll embedding

Tags: c#, wix, .net-2.0, wix2

I'm trying to embed a .dll into a wix installer that is used by other dlls during the install but will not be installed onto the customer's systems.

I've currently got

```
<Binary Id="AutomationUtils" SourceFile="AutomationUtils\bin\Release\AutomationUtils.dll" />
...
<CustomAction Id="Install" BinaryKey="InstallUILib" DllEntry="AutomationUtils;RunInstallerDLL" Return="check" Execute="deferred" />
```

but even if I take the other .dll out - WiX refuses to acknowledge the existance of the AutomationUtils .. even though it builds ok (but falls over when you try and run it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BinaryKey='InstallUILib'` will refer to a `Binary` element with `Id='InstallUILib'`. The `CustomAction/@DllEntry` attribute is the name of the function entry point into the custom action .dll in the `Binary` element. That name needs that [::GetProcAddress()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can access. I'm pretty sure a function named `AutomationUtils;RunInstallerDLL` is not valid.

If you're looking to do managed code custom action (where you probably need multiple .dlls) this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132918/Creating-Custom-Action-for-WIX-Written-in-Managed) is okay. Otherwise, if you're creating a native custom action, I recommend creating a single .dll.

Comment: InstallUILib and RunInstallerDLL sure sound a lot like InstallUtilLib and RunInstaller.   Hmmmm....

Comment: @Chris Such a dirty hack attempt on my part can only suggest that I'm working on something that I've never looked at before :)

Rob, This limitation is quite a hindrance and I'm seriously considering copy/paste (as horrible as it is). I guess what I really need is a .net2 compatible method for embedding dlls into another dll that can be easily programmatically automated (and does not add to the build requirements)- but that's a different question.

Or this: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Easy-WiX-way-for-a-custom-action-to-call-multiple-utility-DLLs-td705940.html

Comment: @Izzy, since you tagged it wix2 I'm guessing you aren't using DTF.  Correct?  DTF is the gold standard for authoring managed custom actions and it already has a built in mechanism for packaging up dependencies and references and making them available at runtime.

Comment: @Izzy like Christopher pointed out, use DTF which is that article I pointed at. It will address all the problems correctly.

Comment: Yeh, I guess I was a little dense the first time I looked at that article.